# what is the difference between Boolean('') is false and Boolean(new String(''))?

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression

I have a doubt that both are **strings** why getting different Boolean values **Boolean('')** is false and **Boolean(new String(''))?**

Comment: A string *primitive* is not the same as a String *object*.

Comment: Similarly: `Boolean(new Boolean(false))` is `true`. Any non null object as argument to `Boolean` gives you `true`.

Answer (score 3):

The `Boolean` function returns `true` for all object references. `new String("")` creates a string *object*. In contrast, `""` is just a string primitive; `Boolean` returns `false` for a blank string primitive.

When called as a function (rather than as a constructor), [`Boolean`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-boolean-constructor-boolean-value) returns the result of the spec's [`ToBoolean` abstract operation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-toboolean):

> The abstract operation ToBoolean converts argument to a value of type Boolean according to Table 9:
>
> ```
> +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
> |                 Table 9: ToBoolean Conversions                  |
> +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
> | Argument Type | Result                                          |
> +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
> | Undefined     | Return false.                                   |
> +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
> | Null          | Return false.                                   |
> +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
> | Boolean       | Return argument.                                |
> +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
> | Number        | If argument is +0, −0, or NaN, return false;    |
> |               | otherwise return true.                          |
> +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
> | String        | If argument is the empty String (its length is  |
> |               | zero), return false; otherwise return true.     |
> +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
> | Symbol        | Return true.                                    |
> +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
> | Object        | Return true.                                    |
> +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
> ```

As you can see from the last row in the table, anything that's an object will result in `true`.

Answer (score 0):

1. The following values are coerced to `false` because are `falsy` values: `''`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `null`, `0`.
2. Everything else will be coerced to `true` because are `truthy` values.

*What you're trying to do with:*

```
Boolean('') // Coercing a primitive empty string (falsy).
```

*And with the following:*

```
Boolean(new String('')) // Coercing an object (truthy).
```